# TimeConstrained dynamic change of maximum time

Tags: dynamic, evaluation, interruption, date-and-time

I would like to run a time consuming function:

```
TimeConstrained[f[x],maxseconds]
```

and be able to change maxseconds during running (increasing or decreasing max time) using a slider. Ideally when i decrease maxseconds below the time it has already consume it will stop.

I could implement such a functionality inside f but i would have to do this for all f i want to create , so this way is out of the question.

Thanks in advance,

Theodore.

Comment: This is a tough one. Basically it boils down to the fact that once a long calculation is started, you cannot interrupt it programmatically from the outside (i.e. not from the inside as in case of e.g. `EventMonitor:>If[aborted, Abort[]]`) with any `Abort[]`, even using a background scheduled task to monitor elapsed time.

Comment: I understand your point. This is why I opened the bounty - in case there is a way of generalizing `TimeConstrained` maybe with some low level Java programming?

Comment: Perhaps ["EvaluatorAbort"](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/frontendobject/EvaluatorAbort.html) could be used.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelE2 for the input!

Comment: Another completely different approach would be to abuse one of the parallel kernels to run the computation in a  *detached thread*. After all, the parallel kernels are just simple kernels you can use for calculation. In this way you could work in the front end while your `f[x]` is calculated in the background and you can stop the calculation at any time.

Comment: @halirutan I thought of this also, but I have zero experience in parallel computing. I would love to see an example though, do you have the time to design an answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to Michael E2's comment, the following approach is successful. The method sets up a scheduled task that (at certain resolution `res`) monitors the elapsed `$time` and compares it to the dynamic `$max`. If `$time` is more than allowed by `$max`, it calls the front-end `"EvaluatorAbort"`.

```
Attributes[dynamicTimeConstrained] = {HoldAll};
dynamicTimeConstrained[expr_] := Module[{task, res = .1},
   $time = 0;
   task = RunScheduledTask[(
      $time = $time + res;
      If[$time >= $max,
       RemoveScheduledTask@task;
       FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`CellPrint@Cell[
           "Aborted at "<>ToString@$time<>".", "Output"];
           FrontEndExecute@FrontEndToken@"EvaluatorAbort"
          ];
      ), {res, Infinity}];
   res = expr;
   RemoveScheduledTask@task;
   res
   ];

$time = 0;
$max = 3;
Dynamic@$time

(* set up slider to dynamically manipulate $max *)
Slider[Dynamic@$max, {0.0001, 10}, Appearance -> "Labeled"]

(* simulate a long calculation by Pause *)
dynamicTimeConstrained[Do[Pause@1; Print[i];, {i, 5}]; 111]
```

Notice that the scheduled task is aware of the global value changes to both `$time` and `$max`, so the method works. May need a bit of fine tuning on the correct time-resolution as too fine a resolution might cause delayed abortion.

Here the default allotted time (3 sec) is extended, so the calculation terminates normally without abort:

[image]

Here the default time (3 sec again) is decreased and the job aborts as expected:

[image]

Comment: Great job!  Glad the comment helped. :)

Comment: @tchronis Thanks for the accept and the bounty! I hope this method can be used in realistic situations as well.